# Entity Framework Core error when modifying entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

It's the first time for me using DDD to design my domain models. My current domain model `Auction` looks like this:

```cs
public class Auction
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; private set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; private set; }

    public Stage Stage { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; private set; } = new List<Bid>();

    private Auction() { }

    public static Auction Create(ApplicationUser creator, DateTimeOffset createdAt)
    {
        return new Auction
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Creator = creator,
            CreatedAt = createdAt,
            Stage = Stage.Active
        };
    }

    public void PlaceBid(Bid bid)
    {
        if (BidIsGreaterThanCurrentHighestBid(bid) == false)
        {
            throw new InvalidBidException("Bid amount must be greater than the current highest bid.");
        }

        Bids.Add(bid);
    }

    private bool BidIsGreaterThanCurrentHighestBid(Bid bid)
    {
        var highestBid = Bids
            .OrderByDescending(b => b.Amount)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return highestBid == null || bid.Amount > highestBid.Amount;
    }
}
```

I've now created a command to actually place a new bid. Here is the code for the command handler:

```cs
public class PlaceBidCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<PlaceBidCommand>
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;

    public PlaceBidCommandHandler(IApplicationDbContext dbContext,
        IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _identityService = identityService;
    }

    public async Task Handle(PlaceBidCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var user = await _identityService.GetUserAsync();

        var auction = await _dbContext.Auctions
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == request.AuctionId, cancellationToken);

        var bid = Bid.Create(user, auction, request.Amount);

        auction.PlaceBid(bid);

        _dbContext.Auctions.Entry(auction).State = EntityState.Modified;

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

First of all it does not feel right to save the entity by setting the state manually. Anyways, if or if not, the code doesn't work.

This is the error I get:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

---

**Edit 01:** The error does not occur when I change the command handler to this:

```
public async Task Handle(PlaceBidCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var user = await _identityService.GetUserAsync();

        var auction = await _dbContext.Auctions
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == request.AuctionId, cancellationToken);

        var bid = Bid.Create(user, auction, request.Amount);

        await _dbContext.Bids.AddAsync(bid, cancellationToken);

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

I don't want to add the bid like this. I would like to add it with my Auction model.

---

**Edit 02:** Here is my EF mapping:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Auction> Auctions => Set<Auction>();

    public DbSet<Bid> Bids => Set<Bid>();

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Auction>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Bids)
            .WithOne(e => e.Auction)
            .HasForeignKey("AuctionId")
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Auctions)
            .WithOne(e => e.Creator)
            .HasForeignKey("CreatorId")
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bid>()
            .HasOne(b => b.Bidder)
            .WithMany();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bid>()
            .HasOne(b => b.Auction)
            .WithMany(a => a.Bids);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Does anybody knows how I could do this? - I highly appreciate any kind of help! :)

Comment: You don't need `Entry(auction).State = EntityState.Modified;` to tell EF Core that `auction` was modified unless you disabled change tracking. Which, in this case, would be a bug

Comment: As for the code itself, DDD has *nothing* to do with how you configure your ORM and objects. `Auction` in this case isn't a domain entity. Right now, the properties can't be set when the DTOs are loaded. To use [read-only properties, you must provide a constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#read-only-properties). Without this, the ID and other values remain null or default, so when EF Core tries to save the object, it ends up saving nothing

Comment: Like @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned, DDD is persistence agnostic.  You also fail to encapsulate your collection and expose it as public so any developer can come along and call auction.Bids.Add(....) and bypass and bid placing logic you put in PlaceBid

Comment: you also should include your entity EF mappings if you are having trouble saving.  sounds like you missed a bi-directional mapping between the entities.
Guid.NewGuid() also isn't great.  If you are going to detemine Guid's on the client, you want to look into a CombGuid so that the id's are sequential. if you allow EF to generate the Guid it will be a sequential guid.

Comment: @Fran First of all, thanks for your advices - You totally right, I've missed that - Probably going to use ReadOnlyCollection soon then as a second property... I've also added the EF mappings now :)

Comment: that mapping does look funky.  i'm confused by all the inheritence here.  I'd probably simplify it with just inheriting from DbContext for the time being until you work out the mapping issues.  I'm confused by the Auction mapping with a WithOne.  I'd start with deleting that Auction mapping.  add withforeignkey on the bid mapping. I also prefer using the arrow notation for foreignkey mapping in case EF does something funky.
I also like to create a migration and push that out to a db so that I can check all the relationships created in SQLServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Fran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187365/fran) already said in the comments:

> that mapping does look funky.

After some time, I finally found a suiting solution. Here the insight in the `OnModelCreating()` method:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ----- Auction entity -----

    modelBuilder.Entity<Auction>()
        .HasKey(a => a.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Auction>()
        .Property(a => a.Id)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Auction>()
        .HasOne(a => a.Creator)
        .WithMany(c => c.Auctions)
        .HasForeignKey("CreatorId")
        .IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Auction>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Bids)
        .WithOne(b => b.Auction)
        .HasForeignKey("AuctionId")
        .IsRequired();

    // ----- Bid entity -----

    modelBuilder.Entity<Bid>()
        .HasKey(b => b.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Bid>()
        .Property(b => b.Id)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Bid>()
        .HasOne(b => b.Auction)
        .WithMany(a => a.Bids)
        .HasForeignKey("AuctionId")
        .IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Bid>()
        .HasOne(b => b.Bidder)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("BidderId")
        .IsRequired();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}i
```

I've also changed the `Auction` entity to this:

```cs
public class Auction
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; private set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; private set; }

    public Stage Stage { get; private set; }

    private ICollection<Bid> _bids = new List<Bid>();

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Bid> Bids => _bids.ToList().AsReadOnly();

    private Auction() { }

    public static Auction Create(ApplicationUser creator,
        DateTimeOffset createdAt)
    {
        return new Auction
        {
            Creator = creator,
            CreatedAt = createdAt,
            Stage = Stage.Active
        };
    }

    public void PlaceBid(Bid bid)
    {
        if (BidIsGreaterThanCurrentHighestBid(bid) == false)
        {
            throw new InvalidBidException("Bid amount must be greater than the current highest bid.");
        }

        _bids.Add(bid);
    }

    private bool BidIsGreaterThanCurrentHighestBid(Bid bid)
    {
        var highestBid = _bids
            .OrderByDescending(b => b.Amount)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return highestBid == null || bid.Amount > highestBid.Amount;
    }
}
```

The main changes were:

1. Entity Framework now generates the ID's for my entities.
2. Added a backing field so that there is no way to bypass the method `PlaceBid()`

Comment: Just a stylistic note, you can group all the model builder calls to one entity using { } and the  => notation

Comment: @Fran Thanks for the hint, one thing I already did was moving them into own configuration files, where they derive from `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>`.